# Where is the wireless configuration on Fedora 23?

Tags: fedora, wifi, rpm

I am entirely new to Linux as I just installed the dual boot of Windows 10 and Fedora. And the problem  I ran into is that in the network setting, there is no option for WiFi? I did intensive Google search and yield no good result. None of the installing packages from the terminal seemed to work... Maybe I should switch to a different distro?

image after running `lspci`: [image](http://s8.postimg.org/c75gufhud/IMG_20151204_114038738.jpg)

Comment: Have you read the [documentation?](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/23/html/Networking_Guide/ch-Introduction_to_Fedora_Networking.html) Also, what WiFi adapter are you using? Switching distros will probably not make a difference. Add details to your question :-)

Comment: yeah, I read some parts of docs and it did not help. And also I am using Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter

Comment: @garethTheRed for some reason, gcc and a lot of other packages don't even come with it...

Comment: I'm sure you'll be able to install `gcc` - once you've got wireless working.  There are many Broadcom adapters - run `lspci` in a terminal and post that as an edit to your question.  Broadcom isn't the best chipset for Linux support.

Comment: @garethTheRed sir, I added it.

Comment: There seems to a few options open to you, but they'll all involve downloading extra packages.  Google 'fedora BCM4312' and you'll see a few.  Try to keep to the latest ones as things change at quite a pace so a 4 year old blog might not be relevant any more.  Try not to use `ndiswrapper` if you can help it.  Fortunately, you have an ethernet adapter so you can use that to download the extra packages.

Comment: Please replace the image by text (images aren't searchable, for one). We only need the line for the WiFi adapter here.

Comment: Switching to a different distribution is unlikely to fix your problem. All distributions for desktop use are based on (more or less) the same kernel and drivers. Third party drivers (i.e., ones from the manufacturer) are broken or stale most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fedora updates regularly break the functioning of Broadcom wireless devices. That's very annoying.

I have a HP laptop with a Broadcom BCM43228 wifi card. The following, taken from [this blog post](http://antoine.hordez.fr/2015/07/28/howto-bcm43228-802-11abgn-on-fedora-2122/), worked for me:

```
wget http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm
wget http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm
rpm -iv rpmfusion-free-release-23.noarch.rpm
rpm -iv rpmfusion-nonfree-release-23.noarch.rpm
dnf clean all
dnf install akmod-wl kernel-devel
akmods --force
```

(If the last command gives you an error "Building and installing wl-kmod failed", it might be that you have installed the wrong architecture for the package `akmod-wl`. In this case, do the following:

```
dnf remove akmod-wl
dnf install akmod-wl.x86_64
```

and retry the `akmods --force` command.)

Then do:

```
modprobe wl
iwconfig
```

The wlo1 wireless interface should be visible now. If it doesn't, do a `systemctl restart NetworkManager`.

Comment: Correction: Broadcom drivers (as written by Broadcom) are *broken*, and tend to make your system misbehave. Use the drivers that come with your kernel.

Comment: @vonbrand Post edited :)

Comment: @dr01 I've tried this and it did not work for me.. `modprobe wl` gives me an error of **could not insert 'wl': required key not available**

Comment: Did the command `akmod` finish successfully?

Answer (score 1):

I believe Fedora ships with NetworkManager. You should be using the `nmcli` command to check the status of, and make changes to, your wireless connections in most cases. Here is the official documentation for nmcli: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Networking/CLI

There is a section specific to Wifi. Also, check the compatibility of you wireless device with Linux. If there is a module available from the manufacturer you might have to manually install it. Best of luck, and welcome to Linux!

Comment: You are right, Fedora sports NetworkManager for quite a few releases now. Works like a charm.

Comment: @vonbrand , can you describe the steps you follow? i'm running into the same issue

Comment: I also need the steps of solution, could you please explain how? @vonbrand